# Summing up transistor gains

Tags: voltage, transistors, power, amplifier, bias

I was wondering if its possible to sum up transistor gains.

[image: transistors in parallel]

Comment: the arrow in the transistor symbol designates the emitter

Comment: A mistake... Sorry

Comment: It should be on the other Branch

Answer (score 5):

Not like this, no.

Putting these four stages in parallel would pass four times as much current through the array as through a single transistor, but you would need four times the base current as well so the current gain would remain the same.

A Darlington pair multiplies the current gain of the two transistors if that's more suited to what you need.